# Using integer vs character in binary search in data table

Tags: r, data.table, binary-search

Using integers instead of characters as key, to be used in a binary search with data table, seems not to work as expected.

Let's see:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(c1 = c(1,1,2,1,5), c2 = c("B","B","F","C","B"))

# setkey with integer
setkey(dt,c2)
# selecting c2 = "B"
dt["B"]
# result:
#  c1 c2
#1:  1  B
#2:  1  B
#3:  5  B
```

This is correct. But, if we do the same thing with the integer variable:

```
# setkey with C1
setkey(dt,c1)
# selecting c1 = 1
dt[1]
# result:
#    c1 c2
# 1:  1  B
```

This is not correct.

But It works properly using the .() notation:

```
dt[.(1)]
# result:
#   c1 c2
#1:  1  B
#2:  1  B
#3:  1  C
```

We are using only one variable in the search, and I thought it should be possible to use the simple notation, without .(). Then, is it necessary to use .() with integers in any case ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Nope, I think that's only a convenience for character vectors. If you open `?data.table` and read the part for `i` it covers how `character` input is treated specially.

Comment: I've just read, thanks a lot. Additionally, I had thought that if we put only the integer, we are asking really by the number of row ...

Comment: Yep, that's right. Fyi, you can post your own answer to your question (though I think there's some mandatory delay first).